# How to get IPhone's Public IP Address in swift3

Tags: swift3

For my project, i need to get the IPhone's Public IP address, there are so many examples available, which show public IP address by using external / third party URL. I just want to know how to extract IPhone's IP Address without help of using another URL.

I have following code but it gives local IP.

```
func getWiFiAddress() -> String? {
    var address : String?

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return nil }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return nil }

    // For each interface ...
    for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let interface = ifptr.pointee

        // Check for IPv4 or IPv6 interface:
        let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
        if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

            // Check interface name:
            let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
            if  name == "en0" {

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var addr = interface.ifa_addr.pointee
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                getnameinfo(&addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                            &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                            nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                address = String(cString: hostname)
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

    return address
}
```

Comment: By "local" you mean the IP in your local WIFI LAN and by "Public" the one that's "exposed" by your ISP to the outside world ?

Comment: @BogdanFarca yes, correct

Comment: Due to (N)network (A)dress (T)ranslation you can't. What is wrong to read the external address from a website? You need an internet connection anyway to get an external address from your provider.

Comment: @dimple ;So what you want is not possible, like vadian explained. Use an external service to get the IP